# Ruby function to join array with commas and a conjunction

Tags: ruby

Should take an array such as `['dog', 'cat', 'bird', 'monkey']`  and return `'dog, cat, bird and monkey'`.

Looking for a more elegant solution.

```
def self.english_join(array)
  return nil if array.nil?
  return array[0] if array.length == 1
  return array[0..-2].join(', ') + " and " + array[-1] if array.length > 1
end
```

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Rails (actually ActiveSupport, part of the Rails framework) offers a very nice [`Array#to_sentence` method](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v3.1.1/activesupport/lib/active_support/core_ext/array/conversions.rb#L11-35).

If you are using Rails or ActiveSupport, you can call

```
['dog', 'cat', 'bird', 'monkey'].to_sentence
# => "dog, cat, bird, and monkey"
```

The method is automatically customized according to I18n settings. For example, in Italy you should omit the last comma before the `and`.

```
['dog', 'cat', 'bird', 'monkey'].to_sentence
# => "dog, cat, bird e monkey"
```

If you want something without depending on `ActiveSupport`, you can start using the method source code.

This is just an example

```
class Array
  def to_sentence
    default_words_connector     = ", "
    default_two_words_connector = " and "
    default_last_word_connector = ", and "

    case length
      when 0
        ""
      when 1
        self[0].to_s.dup
      when 2
        "#{self[0]}#{options[:two_words_connector]}#{self[1]}"
      else
        "#{self[0...-1].join(options[:words_connector])}#{options[:last_word_connector]}#{self[-1]}"
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: `.to_sentence` is literally magic.

Comment: You've forgotten to add a `options` parameter to the method.

Comment: This is how I discovered `.to_sentence` and oh my goodness, this made my whole day.

Answer (score 5):

```
def english_join(array = nil)
  return array.to_s if array.nil? or array.length <= 1
  array[0..-2].join(", ") + " and " + array[-1]
end
```

A similar but different approach. Combines the joining of a slice of the array with a string append to get the last "and" part.

Comment: However, it might be better to write the last line as `"#{array[0..-2].join(", ")} and #{array.last}"`. `"#{}"` creates fewer String objects than `+`, and so should generally be preferred.

Comment: Also, this doesn't get the comma before the "and".

Answer (score 2):

```
def self.english_join(array = nil)
  return array.to_s if array.nil? or array.length <= 1
  array[-1] = "and #{array[-1]}"
  array.join(', ')
end
```

A different way but not much better. Returns an empty string instead of `nil` if the array is empty. Someone will chime in with a sweet `to_sentence` method.